# CakePHP Date and Database

Tags: mysql, datetime, cakephp

Ok, so I am doing a project that has something to do with uploading files and dates. My application lets users upload files and they can see the documents they have uploaded. They can remove them if they needed to. Once they think the uploaded files are good to go, they can finalize it, meaning they cannot remove the uploaded files. Also, clicking the 'Finalize' button will change the status in the database to 'Submitted' and put a timestamp.

So far, I'm getting an error with these two. Somehow I'm getting this error in my SQL:

UPDATE `leb2`.`docs` AS `Doc` SET `Doc`.`status` = "Submitted", 
`Doc`.`datesubmitted` = 2015-02-14 14:46:21 
WHERE `Doc`.`schoolId` = 15

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:46:21 WHERE `Doc`.`schoolId` = 15' at line 1

These are my codes:

```
public function finalize_init(){
        $this->layout = 'school';
        $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        $this->Doc->id = $id;

        $this->Doc->updateAll(array(
            'Doc.status' => '"Submitted"',
            'Doc.datesubmitted' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ), array(
                'Doc.schoolId'=>$id
                )
        );
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'documents_init'));
    }
```

This is my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE `docs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `schoolId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datesubmitted` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I'm not sure what is the error with the date.

I hope someone can help me out with this. Thank you!

EDIT:

These were in my log

```
Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
1   SELECT `School`.`schoolId`, `School`.`usersId`, `School`.`name`, `School`.`email`, `School`.`term`, `School`.`address`, `School`.`existing_or_new`, `School`.`province`, `School`.`region`, `School`.`type`, `School`.`telephone`, `School`.`fax`, `School`.`dean`, `School`.`dean_email`, `School`.`llm`, `School`.`dean_mobile`, `School`.`president`, `School`.`educational_attainment`, `School`.`status` FROM `leb2`.`schools` AS `School` WHERE `usersId` = 49 LIMIT 1        1   1   1
2   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `leb2`.`docs` AS `Doc` WHERE `Doc`.`schoolId` = 17 AND `Doc`.`status` = 'draft'     1   1   1
3   INSERT INTO `leb2`.`docs` (`schoolId`, `status`) VALUES (17, 'draft')       1   1   30
4   SELECT `Doc`.`id`, `Doc`.`schoolId`, `Doc`.`datesubmitted`, `Doc`.`status`, `School`.`schoolId`, `School`.`usersId`, `School`.`name`, `School`.`email`, `School`.`term`, `School`.`address`, `School`.`existing_or_new`, `School`.`province`, `School`.`region`, `School`.`type`, `School`.`telephone`, `School`.`fax`, `School`.`dean`, `School`.`dean_email`, `School`.`llm`, `School`.`dean_mobile`, `School`.`president`, `School`.`educational_attainment`, `School`.`status` FROM `leb2`.`docs` AS `Doc` LEFT JOIN `leb2`.`schools` AS `School` ON (`Doc`.`schoolId` = `School`.`schoolId`) WHERE `Doc`.`schoolId` = 17 AND `Doc`.`status` = 'draft' LIMIT 1      1   1   1
5   SELECT `Doc`.`id`, `Doc`.`schoolId`, `Doc`.`datesubmitted`, `Doc`.`status`, `School`.`schoolId`, `School`.`usersId`, `School`.`name`, `School`.`email`, `School`.`term`, `School`.`address`, `School`.`existing_or_new`, `School`.`province`, `School`.`region`, `School`.`type`, `School`.`telephone`, `School`.`fax`, `School`.`dean`, `School`.`dean_email`, `School`.`llm`, `School`.`dean_mobile`, `School`.`president`, `School`.`educational_attainment`, `School`.`status` FROM `leb2`.`docs` AS `Doc` LEFT JOIN `leb2`.`schools` AS `School` ON (`Doc`.`schoolId` = `School`.`schoolId`) WHERE `Doc`.`schoolId` = 17 AND `Doc`.`status` = 'draft' LIMIT 1      1   1   1
6   SELECT `Upload`.`iduploads`, `Upload`.`iddocs`, `Upload`.`dest`, `Upload`.`type`, `Upload`.`description`, `Doc`.`id`, `Doc`.`schoolId`, `Doc`.`datesubmitted`, `Doc`.`status` FROM `leb2`.`uploads` AS `Upload` LEFT JOIN `leb2`.`docs` AS `Doc` ON (`Upload`.`iddocs` = `Doc`.`id`) WHERE `Upload`.`iddocs` = 20       0   0   1

Nr  Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
1   UPDATE `leb2`.`docs` AS `Doc` SET `Doc`.`status` = "Submitted", `Doc`.`datesubmitted` = 2015 WHERE `Doc`.`schoolId` = 17 AND `Doc`.`status` = 'draft'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the final query should look like this,

```
UPDATE leb2.docs AS Doc SET Doc.status = "Submitted",  Doc.datesubmitted = '2015-02-14 14:46:21' WHERE Doc.schoolId = 15;
```

the missing on the query was the qoute on the datesubmitted value

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $this->Doc->updateAll(array(
        'Doc.status' => '"Submitted"',
        'Doc.datesubmitted' => "'{$date}'"
        ), array(
            'Doc.schoolId'=>$id
            )
    );
```

to achieve the query,
the datesubmitted value should be enclose with double qoute and single qoute
"'{$date}'"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70942/discussion-between-oli-soproni-b-and-mark).